# after ionic v3 to ionic v5 migration - ionic build command not working

Tags: ionic-framework, webpack, ionic3, ionic5, ionic-appflow

We have migrated from ionic v3 to ionic v5 ... ionic serve command working but showing blank page when launched.

ionic build command throwing following error..

[11:57:17]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
[11:57:17]  TypeError: Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined
at DefinePlugin.apply (/Users/upgrade/node_modules/webpack/lib/DefinePlugin.js:280:18)
at Compiler.apply (/Users/upgrade/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:375:16)
at webpack (/Users/upgrade/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:33:19)
at /Users/upgrade/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/webpack.js:132:24
at new Promise ()
at runWebpackFullBuild (/Users/upgrade/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/webpack.js:113:12)
at webpackWorker (/Users/upgrade/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/webpack.js:70:19)
at Object.webpack (/Users/upgrade/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/webpack.js:29:12)
at bundleWorker (/Users/upgrade/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/bundle.js:13:22)
at Object.bundle (/Users/upgrade/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/bundle.js:6:12)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.

```
    ionic-app-scripts build exited with exit code 1.
    
    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

we need to use this project for all 3 platform i.e. browser, android and ios .. so for that purpose we need www folder with files. ionic build command achieve this.

how should i fix this ...

Comment: i don't know how u did your migration or what plugins u use or anything so its not clear enough, but if you believe your plugins are right and everything in your project app directory is done right, then create a new project which will generate nodemodules folder and package.json, then start copying files from old to new (first app folder, then check if u got things in index.html to new project but not the file itself since things changed with structuring so just in case u got additional scripts etc..., and then global.cscc and them theme variables, then in package.json copy lines of plugins)

Comment: and after you copy lines of plugins to new project, run npm install and it should install new dependencies and after that hopefully you can build your project

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project using ionic 6, migrate cordova plugins to capacitor and copy over code. This is your best bet. Goodluck.